# Change tinymce imagemanager upload folder

Tags: tinymce

I'm using tinymce and imagemanager to upload images.

Any image that I upload is saved in this path: `tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/files/`

It is posiable to change this path to: `uploads/` (outside from the tiny_mce folder) ?

And it is posiable to change the path to `uploads/test/` or `tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/files/test/` - That if test not exist is will create it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this seems to be not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't resolve it with tinyMCE settings. But you can try to implement your own plugin for this. 
[http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/MCImageManager:Creating_a_plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/MCImageManager%3aCreating_a_plugin)

You can try to override method OnAfterUpload that executed after upload files.
You has acces to paths of new files and can make some manipulations. Like this:

```
 public override bool OnAfterUpload(ManagerEngine man, string cmd, NameValueCollection input)
        {
           foreach (string path in man.RootPaths)
           {
                string fileName = input["name"];
                // create new folder if necessary. Copy files etc

           }

            return true;
        }
```